# Corollaries to the inversion formula (Durrett)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

In [Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)'s §3.3, he proves:

> **Theorem 3.3.11: the inversion formula.** Let $\varphi(t)=\int e^{itx}\mu(dx)$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure. If $a<b$ then $\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim\limits_{T\to\infty}\int_{-T}^T\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}\varphi(t)dt=\mu((a,b))+\frac{\mu(\{a,b\})}{2}$.

He then states two corollaries:

> **Corollary 3.3.12.** If $\varphi$ is real then $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution. [it is implicit that $\varphi(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$ is $X$'s characteristic function]
>
> **Corollary 3.3.13.** If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent with distributions $N(0,\sigma_1)$ and $N(0,\sigma_2)$, then $X_1+X_2$ has distribution $N\left(0,\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}\right)$.

I'm at a loss to see how these corollaries follow. For the first, would it be using $\mu(A):=\mathbb{P}[X\in A]$? For the second, I suspect it somehow uses $\varphi=\varphi_1\varphi_2$ where these are the characteristic functions for (resp.) $X_1+X_2$, $X_1$, and $X_2$, but I'm not really seeing the big picture here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inversion Theorem tells us, in particular, that if two probability measures have the same characteristic function then they are identical: Suppose $\mu ((a,b))+\frac {\mu (\{a,b\})} 2=\nu ((a,b))+\frac {\nu (\{a,b\})} 2$ whenever $a<b$. Then $\mu ([a,b))=\nu ([a,b))$ except for countably many values of $a, b$. [ Because $\mu (\{a\})=0=\nu (\{a\})$ except for countably many values of $a$]. Now it follows by a  standard measure theoretic argument that $\mu (E)=\nu (E)$ for all Borel sets $E$.

For the first corollary just check that $X$ and $-X$ have the same characteristic function. [$\mathbb E e^{-itX} $ is the complex conjugate of $\mathbb E e^{itX} $].

For the second corollary use the fact that characteristic function of $X_1+X_2$ is the product of the characteristic functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$. It follows that the characteristic function of $X_1+X_2$ is same as that of $N(0,\sqrt {\sigma_1^{2}+\sigma_2^{2}})$ which implies that $X_1+X_2$ has this normal distribution.